# how to implement Switch-Case in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to implement switch-case statement in Python. I need help because this print nothing on console. I want to trigger some functions with this switch.

```
def do_something():
    print("do")


def take_something():
    print("take")


switch = {
    "do": do_something,
    "take": take_something
}


def execute_command(command):
    switch.get(command, lambda: print("Invalid command!"))


execute_command(input())
```

Comment: you never call the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You r almost right.

```
def execute_command(command):
    switch.get(command, lambda: print("Invalid command!"))() # maybe args
```

since switch.get returns a function

or more sofisticated way with globals() returns dict of current global variables:

```
def dojob():
    print("do")


def takejob():
    print("take")


 def execute_command(command):
    globals().get(command, lambda: print("Invalid command!"))()

execute_command(input())
```

and enter dojob, takejob

Answer (score 1):

This line: `switch.get(command, lambda: print("Invalid command!"))` is retrieving the function but you aren't doing anything with it. You have to call the function by adding `()` like so:

```
switch.get(command, lambda: print("Invalid command!"))()
```